# FrameLayout dies when SlidingMenu shown

Tags: android, android-framelayout, slidingmenu

I want to make sliding menu for my app using SlidingMenuLibrary and fragments.

I use this code to add content to the FrameLayout:

```
    FragmentManager fm = MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    Layout1 fragment = new Layout1();
    ft.add(R.id.activity_main_content_fragment, fragment);
    ft.commit();
```

Layout1 xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Layout 1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="38dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT 1**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <!-- This is where fragment will show up -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_content_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title" >
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My app work fine, I slide the menu without any problems but when I slide the menu to left to hide it, the FrameLayout dies, nothing keep working, the progressbar stop loading and the editText becomes enabled.

Comment: Can you provide the activity's xml?

Comment: yes of course, show the edit 1